# Is there any custom DWM (Desktop Window Manager) for Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, dwm

So my question is is there any custom DWM that can entirely replace explorer.exe and window frames on Windows 8, and if not is it even possible to create one?

Comment: Explorer is not really a Window Manager. It’s essentially just the taskbar and desktop icons.

Comment: You can probably find the answer you are looking for by Googling "replace Windows shell" or "skinning Windows." @DanielB is correct that Windows doesn't really have a Desktop WIndow Manager in the same way that *nix systems do.

Comment: @Lucijan - Terminology: There's no such generic term as "DWM". There are "[window managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager)" and "[desktop environments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment)". "[Desktop Window Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_Window_Manager)" is the name of MS's compositing window manager that is used in Windows 7 onwards. Also explorer.exe is not a window manager (it is a part of the Windows desktop environment). So what you are probably asking is: "Is there a window manager that can replace DWM for Windows 8, or can one be created?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Windows user interface is, compared to DWMs on Linux based destributions, connected deeper to the actual OS. This makes replaceing the UI harder.

There are projects which try to replace some parts of it. For example the start menu of Windows 8 ([StartIsBack](http://startisback.com/)). Here is a list of Windows Shell replacements: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_alternative_shells_for_Windows.